# How to facilitate multiple options whilst emphasizing 1 option in particular?

Tags: mobile, interface, options, use-cases

In this screen we have six options which can be toggled to suit the users preferences. All of these preference options are necessary to the product.

However, in 90% of use cases the users will only choose preference Option 3.

How can I optimize the UI to suit this use case? Would changing the order of the options help? Is there something else I can try besides that?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand it completely, is it mandatory that all 6 options are enabled before the product can work? Or are these options there so that you can gather extra data / make more money when they are enabled?

Comment: No, the only requirement is that one option is selected. 90% of the time it will be Option 3.

Comment: Sorry did an edit on my comment when i re-read it and it sounded a bit harsh. Did not mean that. Anyway, to my understanding that if they only select option 3 most of users are just looking for that option or the other options are not good enough for the user to enable them. The initial user research might have been insufficient.

Comment: Would it harm the user if you always select the 3rd option, as a default preference? That's what it sounds to me, a default which you can deviate from.

Placing the 3rd on top sounds good, although it would depend on whether it makes sense. If the options are a logical sequence I wouldn't do it. Simple example: you probably wouldn't place C first if the range was A, B, C, D.

Comment: Please put some vertical space between the options. People's fingers aren't as small (or accurate) as you think

Comment: @bace1000 it's actually following the table row height from iOS https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/tables/

Comment: Then it's bad advice and you should ignore it

Comment: Imagine you're doing user testing and the tester keeps pressing the wrong button by accident, would you completely ignore them because "the guidelines say the spacing is enough"? This is why mobile interfaces are almost always horrible to use. The notion of blindly copying whatever Apple spouts is the reason why nearly all mobile software sucks.

Comment: @bace1000 of course not. But that is yet to be seen/reported yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If the 90% use case is a specific option, you can label it 'recommended', and explain why if needed.

#### Is the act of selection explicit?

If you want to keep the action of choosing an option up to the customer (it sounds like your use case requires a choice), you can lead them to the most common with a simple label showing what the vast majority do.

#### Ordering of choices

You could put the recommended up at the top, but I'm not sure if the order of choices needs to be specific.

[image: y]

Comment: Would it be beneficial to put the initial (recommended) option as the first one as well? Or would that be a problem?

Comment: @BryceSnyder I agree that the (recommended) be at the top, but it depends on if the order makes logical sense.

Comment: Useful answer! What about having the recommended option turned on by default?

Comment: I don't know the constraints, which is why I phrased that part as a question. Having the recommended on by default could work well, if the options don't need to be explicitly selected...

Comment: @MikeM there are no constraints in this case regarding that, so it would improve the answer. Thanks again.